# CSS not updating on change

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webmatrix, updating

When I try and change my current CSS or add new CSS to my style-sheet no change shows up (tags are still being styled by the old unchanged code).

For example, if I delete the contents of a class and I go into chrome debug tool using <kbd>F12</kbd>, I can see that the contents which I deleted are still showing up - even if I clear the cache by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, OR by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>!

All the other files of my website seem to be updating correctly, so if I use inline styles it will update correctly.

Strangely when I go into my websites control panel and manually download the CSS style-sheet from my server I can see that the code has indeed being updated with the new code, this is weird because upon inspecting it with <kbd>F12</kbd>, I can still see the old code with no changes.

- I am using Microsoft Webmatrix to do my coding.
- I am using the Chrome Web browser.
- I am using Hostgator hosting.

I've exhausted all my trouble shooting options and have been beat by something that by all means should not occur. I think I've had a problem like this before and I think that it was solved by just waiting a day for whatever magic to work but I shouldn't have to wait. A problem like this is absolutely unacceptable in a live environment. Any ideas of what could be causing this?

#### FIXED!

changed: https://example.com/app/source/css/main.css

to this: https://example.com/app/source/css/main.css?v=1

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that the CSS you are seeing is in a different location from the one you want to see. Verify the <link> in the head

Comment: Wow things just got stranger.. when i checked the link on the head (which is the correct path) and i clicked on it, it showed me all the CSS in that file. Except now it shows me the old unchanged code inside! Why is this happening even though when i manually viewed the CSS from my website on the control panel it showed the proper changed code? Its like the Hostgator server has some sort of weird cache.

Comment: It gets even weirder.. when i removed the content from a class and looked at it from F12 debug tool its showing that the styling is now coming from <style></style> tags even though i never use them. when i click on the text it just links me to the the previous main style-sheet... why q.q

Comment: What you can try is add ?v=1 behind the URL of the CSS link

Comment: WHAT A HERO! yes that worked! wow! Please write an answer and i will gladly accept it. and maybe even include an explanation of why this works :)

Comment: Gerard's answer worked because Chrome had cached the CSS file. by adding a version number it forced the browser to get the latest version. While developing JS or CSS changing it's usually a good idea to clear your cache (Ctrl+Shift+Delete) > Cached images and files

Comment: @Simon so Ctrl + Shift + R or Ctrl + F5 doesn't actually fully clear the cache then? Never knew that.

Comment: No. That just calls the server again (both are just refreshes). Physically clearing the cache is best. BTW, using ?V=1 (or sequential numbers for each release) will also ensure that users revisiting your page after a release won't experience the same issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ?v=1 behind the URL of the CSS link in the head, which will force using a non-cached version, because of the different (new) file name. The number should be unique, so if you want to use this in the future, make sure to replace the 1.

Answer (score 2):

You could try ctrl + shift + r (on a PC) to hard reset the browser and make sure the cache isn't displaying old CSS.

One thing is to verify you are editing the correct file. I managed to have that issue one time when I had two files named the same, but one was outside the folder with the index.html and that was the one I was editing.